How to map EDI file looped items in Boomi?
This is my EDI file:
UNH+19472232+ORDERS:D:96A:UN:EAN008'
BGM+220::9+19472232'
DTM+137:20170823:102'
DTM+2:20171031:102'
NAD+BY+8714252029536::9'
NAD+SU+4046568000003::9'
NAD+DP+8714252029536::9'
NAD+IV+8714252029536::9'
NAD+UC+8714252029536::9'
LIN+1++8718885840155:EN'
PIA+5+69706-333-000:SA'
QTY+21:3:PCE'
LIN+2++9000068400333:EN'
PIA+5+68400-333-000:SA'
QTY+21:3:PCE'

I am using EDI Profile in Boomi and mapping the result into a Flat File Profile.
My problem is that the result is duplicate all of the other data.
19472232 ORDERS D 96A UN EAN008
220    19472232
137 20170823 102
2 20171031 102
BY87142520295369
SU40465680000039
DP87142520295369
IV87142520295369
UC87142520295369
**18718885840155EN
569706-333-000SA
213PCE**
19472232 ORDERS D 96A UN EAN008
220    19472232
137 20170823 102
2 20171031 102
BY87142520295369
SU40465680000039
DP87142520295369
IV87142520295369
UC87142520295369
**29000068400333EN
568400-333-000SA
213PCE**

So the LIN, PIA and QTY mapped well.
But all of the others mapped twice which is not good.
Here are some images:




I solved it. I moved to JSON Profile instead of Flat File Profile.
I added 3 array: LIN, PIA and QTY.
